# Launching a custom view from a custom model. Zend_possible?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

You have to promise not to giggle, but my situation is following:

Instead of using partials and helpers and other similar tools that we use already, we want to use a custom view outside all frames and borders of the actual application. Basically, we need at this point to load clean HTML into a variable upon a certain reaction a model. That is monkeys business and can be done by virtually anyone without using a keyboard.

The problem is that the HTML pages that we want to create are supposed to be quite extensive and are a trainwreck to debug/maintain/expand due to the inate "return $arrlglllgll;" approach. To make a smooth and humane script, we would very much love to use the .phtml style with clean html mixed up with php injections without actually **rendering** it.

Is that possible and how?

I am currently struggling with

```
$mailView = new Zend_View();
$mailView->setScriptPath('/Templates');
echo($mailView->render('test.php'));
die;
```

Where test.php is a file I have been trying to reach with any means and corelations imaginable, but ultimately failed every time due to

```
 exception 'Zend_View_Exception' with message 'script 'test.php' not found in path (\library\Extras\Controller\Action\Helpers\)' in \library\Zend\View\Abstract.php:875
Stack trace: blablabla
```

Loading a custom view from a controller is butt-easy, just provide the relative path and you're set, but it seems that I cannot find anything if I shoot from within a library. Any advice?

Comment: Is `/Templates` your actual, absolute path? Try dumping the contents of `$view->getScriptPaths()` before rendering, and add that output to your question.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => \Templates\
)

Basically, it's exactly what I set it to, plus one slash. And I don't have any problems calling the view from the controller with '../applications/views/scripts/controller/test.php'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anybody wonders, this is a lot easier than I ever thought it to be...

```
// Set the view
$layout = new Zend_Layout();
$view = $layout->getView();

// Send inherited custom parameters
$view->params = $params;
```

You can thus use the $view as a real view and load any $view->helper as you please.

To save rendered view, type...

```
$savingParameter = $view->render('controller/subfolder/' . $page . '.phtml');
```

TADAA